# C++ Project: Artifact-Name dependant "include" directory population using CMake (build-time)

Tags: c++, directory, cmake, project, structure

I've devised a good structure for a new project which I currently successfully use.

**NOTE:** This structure is beneficial for the project which is developed by multiple programmers.

```
<Project Directory>
    + include
        + Haroogan
            + Utility
                - util.h
            + More
                - more.h
                + Whatever
                    - whatever.h

    + src
        + Haroogan.More             <--- Artifact
            - more.h
            - more.cpp
            - CMakeLists.txt
        + Haroogan.More.Whatever    <--- Artifact
            - whatever.h
            - whatever.cpp
            - CMakeLists.txt
        + Haroogan.Utility          <--- Artifact
            - util.h
            - util.cpp
            - CMakeLists.txt
        + Haroogan.Application      <--- Artifact
            - app.h
            - app.cpp
            - CMakeLists.txt
        - CMakeLists.txt            <--- "Root" CMakeLists.txt
```

**Artifact** - is library, executable, etc. - you got the point.

**Artifact-Name** (as in the subject) - is simply the name of the artifact which is deduced by CMake from the name of the directory dedicated to the artifact. Actually terms Artifact and Artifact-Name are essentially the same. For example: artifact residing in directory "Haroogan.More.Whatever" has name "Haroogan.More.Whatever".

This has several consequences:

- library, executable, etc. produced after a build will be named with Artifact-Name;
- all source code pertaining to a particular artifact is enclosed in a namespace corresponding to the Artifact-Name. For instance: artifact "Haroogan.More.Whatever" imposes "Haroogan::More::Whatever" namespace on all its sources;
- when one artifact wants to use another one, then one has to include another one's headers and optionally link against it. However, we all know writing `#include "../Haroogan.More/more.h"` not only looks messy, but also breaks the basic idea that artifacts actually represent stand-alone components which have to be decoupled even in terms of file-system. Moreover, the concept of private headers is also broken, because this way I can access any headers inside other artifacts.

What we need here is simply a **public header repository** - the "include" directory. Therefore, to address the last issue - I decided to do the following:

- each artifact decides (in its CMakeLists.txt of course) on its own which headers it wants to export to the outside world;
- then it copies (on every build, but only when needed of course) these header files to the corresponding directory inside "include". For instance, if Artifact-Name is "Haroogan.More.Whatever" then headers will be copied to "include/Haroogan/More/Whatever/" directory (as shown above).

I believe it's a nice and robust approach since now if I want to use "whatever" and "more" classes from "Haroogan.More.Whatever" and "Haroogan.More" artifacts in other components - I simply write:

```
#include <Haroogan/More/Whatever/whatever.h>
#include <Haroogan/More/more.h>

using Haroogan::More::Whatever::whatever;
using Haroogan::More::more;
```

The system works like a charm (I can provide CMake scripts if anybody wants). However, I'm not satisfied with the fact that headers are copied. It would be much better if, for example, instead of copying "whatever.h" CMake would create new file "whatever.h" in "Haroogan/More/Whatever/" and **inject** `#include "../../../../src/Haroogan.More.Whatever/whatever.h"` in it.

My system right now it fully automated. In other words, path "Haroogan/More/Whatever" is automatically deduced from Artifact-Name "Haroogan.More.Whatever". Therefore, it would be great if **injection** of `#include "../../../../src/Haroogan.More.Whatever/whatever.h"` with all those nasty `../../` would be also automated.

Unfortunately, I'm new to CMake and don't know how to achieve this functionality, but I think it is possible and might be already done by someone. Thank you.

**EDIT:**

A temporary solution for this problem could be the following:

Instead of creating "whatever.h" inside "Haroogan/More/Whatever/" which immediately leads to dealing with `../../` mess, I could simply create "Haroogan.More.Whatever.whatever.h" (by prefixing "whatever.h" with "Haroogan.More.Whatever") right in the "include" directory and use it as:

```
#include <Haroogan.More.Whatever.whatever.h>

using Haroogan::More::Whatever::whatever;
```

This solution is acceptable, but I don't like it as much as the one I'm interested in.

Comment: An alternate approach would be if each CMake-project in your structure defines a set of CMake-Project_INCLUDE_DIRS which can then be managed on the CMake level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
macro(add_public_headers)
  foreach(header ${ARGN})
    get_filename_component(abspath ${header} ABSOLUTE)
    file(WRITE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${header} "#include ${abspath}"
  endforeach()
endmacro()
```

This maro can be used now in such way:

In `src/Haroogan.More.Whatever/CMakeLists.txt` you do

```
add_public_headers(whatever.h)
```

and this will generate header with single #include line in your build dir.

The only thing is that path would be absolute, but it shouldn't be problem for you.

Comment: So you mean that, although, there are other developers who will pull this project to their machines, I should not care much about making paths relative? In other words, they will get their own absolute paths when they build the project. Well, yeah I'm comfortable with this solution right now. However, if it happens that you find a way to introduce relative path here - I am grateful if you share it. Thanks arrowdodger.

Comment: Right, they will get their own absolute paths. Also, these headers will be regenerated every build.